# in the following grammar

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, objects, reference, subject-vs-object-pronouns

Consider we have the sentence

*My bird likes sunflower seeds. She eats a lot of seeds everyday.*

Using  pronoun resolution we can replace she with the actual subject 'My birds'; converting *'She eats a lot of seeds everyday.'* to *'My bird eats a lot of seeds everyday.  '*

Similarly, assume the below sentences where we have the *'the following * '*  (where * refers to a noun):

1. It stores itself in the following location: \windows.
2. It tries to open the following file: file.exe.
3. The following rows are deleted: row1 row2.

We simply can remove (resolve) *'the following'*  and write them as

1. It stores itself in \windows. (Replaced the '*the following location:*' with the actual  location \windows)
2. It tries to open file.exe. (Replaced 'the following file:' with actual file which it was referring to: file.exe)
3. Row1 and row2 are deleted: row1 and row2. (Replaced 'The following rows' with row1 and row2).

Unlike the 'My bird eats a lot of seeds everyday.' where I used pronoun resolution here I am resolving object with the actual ones. My question is what is this technique? And what is the grammar behind this. Is there any specific naming for *'the following'* ? Any help and insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does 'tones of seeds' mean?

Comment: A lot of seeds.

Comment: Maybe you meant **tons** of seeds? You should be careful because some people would think you really meant tons of seeds, which means a very large bird. 'Tons of' meaning 'a lot of' is slangy and casual. Better to say 'a lot of seeds'. A ton is a measure of weight, either 2,240 pounds, or 1,000 kg.

Comment: Thanks but my question is something else. That was just a toy example which i edited to avoid confusion.

Comment: I edited the third example because it had not been modified at all. But I wasn't sure whether to write "Rows 1 and 2" instead. The phrase "the following" is just a way to introduce the **list** which follows (some containing only one item).

Comment: This seems to be a question about computational linguistics, not English language learning.

Comment: Would you please put some key words in you title, which summarizes your question.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for keyboard? I couldn't think of anything that can describe the question clearly.